# how to get value in array for twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig

i have code

```
{% for defect in data %}
        <tr>

            <td>{{ defect.name }}</td>
             {% for times in time %}
             <td>{{ defect[times] }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

i want to get value {{ defect[times] }}

result defect

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => BORDER
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [13] => 
            [14] => 
            [15] => 
            [16] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [20] => 
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
        )


and result times
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 13
    [6] => 14
    [7] => 15
    [8] => 16
    [9] => 17
    [10] => 18
    [11] => 19
    [12] => 20
    [13] => 21
    [14] => 22
)
```

try to get value {{ defect[times] }} NOT WORKS

thks before

Comment: Posting bad code as a question - what are you expecting for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function, as example:

```
{{ attribute(defect, times) }}
```

Hope this help